# 32-bit version of Zoom for Ubuntu?

Tags: 32-bit, deb, zoom-meeting

I am working on old 32bit pc's, I repair and install ubuntu 16.04 on them and later give them to children in need for education.

zoom 32 bit application cannot be found on the zoom.us website

does anybody have zoom_i386.deb file in there archive ?

Comment: Which error message and Zoom version do you have?

Comment: this the error zoom.us gives for 32 bit ;This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>C03D551B301D3ECD</RequestId>
<HostId>ITBqEuXol/Hxrl9ZFsdTezCgaU82p+JiAzkEfNYdOuaGiK+meNMNlOKj2xG4eSUmZf8606jcZMg=</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: Are you sure that CPUs are not 64-bit capable? What are their models?

Comment: I'd check your boxes as really i386 only as per @N0rbert's suggestion. I used pentium 4, pentium M & i386 only boxes from 2003-2004 in testing Lubuntu 18.04, Xubuntu 18.04 (& later releases [18.10/19.04] though they're EOL now), and that's what I'd choose, as even a 18.04 *flavor* has partial support after April-2021 (when 16.04 reaches it's EOL).  Maybe you know they'll only need the PCs for a few months, but a 18.04 *flavor* will have full-support the same date, and partial support (inc. security upgrades to the base) for two years longer.

Comment: Don't forget 32-bit windows is sold on low-end computers, not because they won't run *amd64* or x86_64 code, but because Microsoft charge $5 less for the 32-bit windows, and most purchasers understood the $5 price far more than the 32bit vs 64bit difference.  I mentioned pentium 4, pentium M.. but also used early intel Atoms too in testing *flavors* (Luibuntu & Xubuntu) up to and including 19.04 though only 18.04 is now supported.

Comment: the pc's that i am working with mostly core2duo, on which ubuntu 16.04 works fine, but older pentium models Lubuntu is good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a 32-bit zoom_i386.deb file version 5.0.398100.0427 from February that I was able to install and run on Ubuntu 18.04. I can send it to you if you wish.

https://zoom.us/client/5.0.398100.0427/zoom_i386.deb

Comment: Other newer alternative is http://zoom.us/client/5.4.53391.1108/zoom_i386.deb .

Comment: Thank you N0rbert , your links did the jobs !

Answer (score 0):

There is a 32bit Debian version on Zoom download site. got it working on a salvaged Dell netbook today using Linux.

Would never go back to Micro$oft!

Comment: Could you actually provide a download link in your answer? That might be helpful. ;-)